# Static page inside dynamic route NuxtJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

i have Nuxt app that have list of cars: **/cars**, there you can choose specyfic one **/cars/:id**. I want inside a toolbar that route to diffrent views: ***/cars/:id/routes**, ***/cars/:id/drivers** etc.

Inside **/cars/:id** i create toolbar and div with `<NuxtChild />`

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-toolbar flat class="rounded-pill " height="50">
      <v-tabs centered slider-color="#356FA4" color="#55BAB4" icons-and-text>
        <v-tab>Overview<v-icon>fa-eye</v-icon></v-tab>
        <v-tab :to="`${$route.params.id}/gauges`"
          >Gauges <v-icon>mdi-gauge</v-icon></v-tab
        >
        <v-tab>Routes <v-icon>mdi-map-marker</v-icon></v-tab>
        <v-tab>Drivers <v-icon>fa-users</v-icon></v-tab>
        <v-tab>Damages <v-icon>fa-car-crash</v-icon></v-tab>
        <v-tab>Documents <v-icon>mdi-file-document-outline</v-icon></v-tab>
        <v-tab>Reminders <v-icon>mdi-alarm</v-icon></v-tab>
      </v-tabs>
    </v-toolbar>
    <div>
      <NuxtChild />
    </div>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

When i click on gauges whole page change, i want to keep toolbar in place. What i missing?

Folder structure:

```
|   index.vue
|   login.vue
|   map.vue
|   organization.vue
|   register.vue
|
+---cars
|   |   index.vue
|   |
|   \---_id
|           gauges.vue
|           index.vue
|
\---users
    |   index.vue
    |
    \---_id
            index.vue
```

[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI3V7.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I test it right now and figured out that you should just put `_id.vue` file instead of `_id/index.vue`. So your folder should be something like this:

```
+---cars
|   |   index.vue
|   |   _id.vue (move your parent codes here)
|   \---_id
|           gauges.vue
|
```

Also there is a good example in nuxt [nested pages](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/routing/nested-pages#nested-pages) docs:

> pages/parent.vue contains the  component. Everything on this page will be seen on both the parent and child pages.
>
> pages/parent/index.vue contains text that will be replaced when the child links are clicked.
>
> pages/parent/child.vue and pages/parent/child2.vue will be rendered as parent/child and parent/child2.